# How to use "extends" in drools spreadsheet?

Tags: inheritance, jboss, drools, xls

So I was looking around to find a way to use the "extends" property of drools in a spreadsheet but didn't find anything about how to use it.

I am looking to move this simple functiuonality used here:
[Drools: modify() or update() only if exists, otherwise add](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21605977/drools-modify-or-update-only-if-exists-otherwise-add)

```
    rule "StartLeftArm" 
when
  $ev: Start()
  $fl:LeftArm()
then
end

rule "create Sample" extends "StartLeftArm"
when
    not Sample( fluent == $fl )
then
    Sample s = new Sample();
    s.setFluent( $fl );
    insert( s );
end
rule "set Sample Value" extends "StartLeftArm"
when
    $s: Sample( fluent == $fl, value != -1.0 )
then
    modify( $s ){ setValue( -1.0 ) }
end
```

Into my excel spreadsheet project.
Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why "create Sample" and "Set Sample value" should be rows in a spreadsheet. (Are you using the right approach for rule authoring?)

Anyway, the best approach would be to define one condition column

$ev: Start() $fl:LeftArm()/*$param*/

join all cells in the column and put a single 'x' in the joined cell.

Comment: Hello, and thanks for the quick reply. The thing is, you focused on the wrong part. This is just an example copied from a previous question that uses the functionality I am interested in. This is not my rule. I would simply like to use the "extends" functionality used in the above drl example, in my excel spreadsheet. I hope that clarifyes it more.

Comment: Why don't you post a question that reflects you problem? Still, the answer would be the same, perhaps with more emphasis on "Are you using the right approach ..."

Comment: Ok, so I reasked the question with a custom written example :) its abit more code and picture examples. I believe I am using the right approach, but please If you believe I am wrong I would like to here better options. The new question is located at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43277402/using-the-extends-functionality-in-drools-spreadsheets